# What do I need to do to compile a C++ program with Embarcado XE7?

Tags: c++, project

I'm trying my first program in this particular environment and it seems unnecessarily complicated.

I've written a header file xxxx.h and a C++ file xxxx.cpp but there doesn't appear to be an option to compile this (where I would expect it to be in the toolbar, the run and/or compile options are greyed out and unavailable).

What am I doing wrong? Maybe I haven't saved these files in the right place or I don't know where they should have been written/created.

I know nothing about this compiler/editor so there may be loads of things that are obvious to an experienced programmer which I'm just not aware of. Do the .h and .cpp files need to be part of a project which ultimately gets compiled? If so, how do I make these files part of that project?

I feel like I couldn't even write a "Hello World" program in this environment with my current knowledge. Please help.

Comment: Please clarify "...this particular environment".  Embedded system?  Desktop PC? Mac? Android Phone?

Comment: Now would probably be a good time to read the manual for your IDE (Embarcadero).

Comment: You may be able to use other IDEs, depends on your platform as to what is available.

Comment: What's the name of the tool you use?

Comment: You probably need more than a source file. Other environments need something like a "project" with a target type like "program", "library" or so. If such a project is part of Embarcadero XE7 you should verify that you have a "program" target.

Answer (score 0):

The IDE(Environment) might require you to make it a project type. If you can't find help or instructions in the program itself, please try the following:
select file, then new. In the drop down box, select project and just read through whatever comes up and click OK. Now, you might already have a .cpp file opened by default. If you do, you are lucky, just type your code in, and you will be able to compile it. Otherwise you have to make a new .cpp file within the project using the project window.

Please bear in mind that I'm saying this with experience only form similar IDEs, not your particular one. If you are a beginner, then probably Borland C++ IDE will be better for you. Not the embarcadero one, the older versions used in the 1998-99 period. Hope this helps. Thanks.